# Any way to make image (gd lib) show only on specific page only?

Tags: php, mysql, security, gdlib

I'm trying to figure out the logistics for a new site that I'm creating, and one of the main issues is to get verification working correctly. One of the verification methods i'd like to incorporate is for a specific image (created via gdlib on the fly) to only work on a web page that is specified in a database field. If the image is shown on the EXACT page that is specified, then it shows the correct image, and if the link is incorrect, then it shows a different image (set by admin). The fields will be created on the admin side, and I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple instances of this working correctly. I'm using PHP and using a tag like [img src="something_here.php"] to show my images. Any suggestions on how to set the coding to verify the site that the image is embedded into?

**Update** So I got it working, but the request_URI command only works for the extension "ex. login.php", as opposed to adding in the absolute domain also. Any suggestions on how to make it factor in the whole domain address?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an image with gd, you can put any PHP code on the page. for example: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/specialWebPage.php') { ... }`.

Comment: Sounds good. Any suggestions on how to code this though? considering I'm pulling info from the database?

Comment: @Eric K. Kwak Well, you can make a connection to the database the way you do on other pages, from the image... Provide me very precise informations, such as database structure and I can provide you a good code `;-)`

Comment: Ok, so I've got a database two tables, one named "user" and another "user_links". When a user types in a URL through the "Add URL" system once logged in, I have that particular users ID (created during registration) copied over to the user_links table, along with whatever link they just added. The "user" table holds all of the registered users info (address, name, etc) and the "user_links" table has two columns, one for user ID and one for the links.

Comment: Now what I'm trying to do is to have a PHP code set up where it will create an image on the fly. I'd like for it to check to see if the URL is in the database, and if so, I'd want it to say verified. If it ISNT in the database, then I want the code to create an image saying unverified. 

I've got it set up to where I can do this with a defined variable at the top of the code, but I can't seem to get it to query the database to check and see if the link is valid. Also, it seems to work when i use something like "/login.php" as the link, but it wont accept the whole url "http://xxxx.com/aa.php"

Comment: this is what i'm using right now:

$ispage = "/gdlib.php";

$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 if ($ispage==$currentpage) {

Comment: The reason why I transferred the ID over to the user_links table is because Im going to want to query just the results for that particular user (links added) so that they can delete, add, or edit the links that they currently have. What do you think about this? any suggestions on making this part more solid? FYI, the IDs are created automatically during registration, and they are 5 numbers long.